# ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) observed when writing to local ServerSocket's OutputStream

Tags: java, android, sockets, socketexception, localserversocket

Hi  guys  I have read the  answer to similar  question but  none of this  could solve the  problem im facing .

> Step 1.) I make a ServerSocket (localhost port8675) , I accept the 
>   socket and get its corresponding   OutputStream (I use  async task for
>   this)
>
> step2.) I get  chunks of data  as byte[] (12kb).
>
> step 3.) I write this  12kb byte[] on the  outputstream.

The  first  chunk  write is  success  but when i try and  write the next  chunk i face this  error.

> > 03-27 21:13:00.275 W/System.err(28866): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275 W/System.err(28866):   at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275 W/System.err(28866):   at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275 W/System.err(28866):   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275 W/System.err(28866):   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275 W/System.err(28866):   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)

These are the  code blocks
Async  task  to make  server socket and  get output stream

```
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {
            providerSocket = new ServerSocket(8765);
            Log.d(TAG,"  ServerSocket made ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG,"ServerSocket failed ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Wait for connection
        Log.d(TAG,"Waiting for connection");
        try {
            connection = providerSocket.accept();
            Log.d(TAG,"Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG,"ServerSocket accept failed ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            dataOutputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            dataOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Now to  write the  byte[] chunks i get

```
  Log.i(TAG, "incoming  data of length ="+data.length);
    new writetask().execute(data); 

protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... temp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(temp[0] != null && (temp[0].length > 0 )){
        Log.d(TAG,"doInBackground of  server  socket start queued data len"+temp[0].length);
        mBuffer =   new byte[temp[0].length];
        mBuffer = temp[0];
       }                
       else 
       { Log.e(TAG,"empty buffer  enqued :(");
        return null ;
       }

        try {
            if(mBuffer != null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, " buffer size = "+temp[0].length);
                Log.d(TAG," write buffer to socket");
                dataOutputStream.write(mBuffer,0,mBuffer.length);} // LINE NO 360.
            else
                Log.e(TAG, "no buffers  are recieved yet");
            mBuffer = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Log.d(TAG,"enqeueBuffer flush the socket");
            dataOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG,"doInBackground run end ");
```

Few  points I have added  only relevant  code , The dataOutputStream is  a classmember  and socket accepting and  outputstream  writing are done in two seprate Async task.

**these are  the logs  for the  1st  data  write which seems  successful**

> > 03-27 21:13:00.150 : incoming  data of length =12288
> >
> > 03-27 21:13:00.155 : doInBackground of  server  socket start
> >
> > 03-27 21:13:00.155  doInBackground of  server  socket start queued
> >     data len12288
> >
> > 03-27 21:13:00.155  buffer size = 12288
> >
> > 03-27 21:13:00.155  write buffer to socket 
> >     03-27  21:13:00.160  flush the socket
> >
> > 03-27 21:13:00.160  doInBackground  run end

**Now the second data  write  logs  are as these**

> 03-27 21:13:00.275  incoming  data of length =12288
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275  doInBackground of  server  socket start
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275  doInBackground of  server  socket start queued
>   data len12288
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275  buffer size = 12288
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275  write buffer to socket
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275 W/System.err(28866): java.net.SocketException:
>   sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
>
> 03-27 21:13:00.275 W/System.err(28866):   at
>   $writetask.doInBackground(SampleServiceImpl.java:360) // fails at
>   write

what is the  reason of this  happening is it  due to output stream  needing to  write  chunks of  data at fast interval (i doubt it  as i have tested much faster  write  rate  at local sockets.)

Kindly  advise.
thanks